# Excel 2016 Connection to MySQL in Data New Query From Database

Tags: mysql, database, excel, connectivity, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet that was created in Excel 2010 and queries a MySQL database using Power Query. I'm trying to use the same query and connection on a new laptop with Windows 10 and Excel 2016. I know that the Power Query functionality has been rolled into the Data tab functionality. I've installed the MySQL installer and Connector/Net. However, I'm unable to see the MySQL option in when going to the Data Tab and selecting New Query From Database.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is only supported on premium SKUs of Office 2013 and 2016. [This link](https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/18/new-ways-to-get-the-excel-business-analytics-features-you-need/) describes the features available to premium SKUs of Office 2016 while the April 2015 section on [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Power-Query-936B2FCA-4168-41AD-BBBD-7B83856B6776) lists the data sources that are only supported in premium SKUs.
This is not enforced on Office 2010 but from a licensing perspective the same restrictions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Can't provide the solution but I can confirm I've been trying this myself this afternoon and I've hit the same problem using a new workbook in Excel 2016.  I found a thread elsewhere on the internet where MS had responded to confirm the PQ version in Excel 2016 is slightly older than the version of PQ available as an add-in.  Since I can't find any ETA on when the bundled version of PQ in Excel 2016 is due to be updated the next step I was going to try was to see if the add-in version of PQ will install as a temporary measure.

Comment: Thanks for the update @CarlWalsh. I can confirm that I've now tried the alternative MySQL method for Excel using this addon instead and found it to work. https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Comment: I've also raised this issue in a number of other places as follows. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79616 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cb998179-1a54-474c-879d-97527aff574f/mysql-datasource-wont-show-up-in-power-query?forum=excel windows-feedback:?contextid=464&feedbackid=4feb4c9a-ef0e-4f17-a297-551f44162d94&form=1&src=1

Answer (score 1):

It's might not answer your question, but you could try out [Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop), which has most of the same Power Query features.